# leave empty space for legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the plotting area the same in these two plots?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=iris, mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data=iris, mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col=Species)) + geom_point()
```

The goal is to overlay plots in an animation and I want the spacing to all be the same.

Comment: Either drop the legend or move it into the plot area.

Comment: You could add `+ guides(color = FALSE)` to remove the legend from the second plot, making the area the same size.

Comment: Can I make an empty space in the first plot?

Comment: If you want to keep the legend I think moving it inside the plot area as suggested by @zx8754 is easier than creating space. For example add: `+ theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9), legend.direction = 'horizontal')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to reserve the space is to allow the legend to be created as it would be in the second plot but to set all the legend elements to be invisible against the background.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=iris, mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep("black", 3)) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.text = element_text(color = "white"), legend.title = element_text(color = "white")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=iris, mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]